# Copy command with variables

Tags: batch-file

on my batch script below, I'm copying a PDF file (my_test01) to an input folder, then I will wait and go to an output folder to copy the output file plus ready in the filename (my_test01-ready) to be send to another location, the script is not finding the output file, because is expecting the same filename as the input.

```
copy /b "%file%" "W:\IP5000_2-up\Input Folder"
TIMEOUT /T 60 /NOBREAK
W:
cd \IP5000_ING_2-up\Processed Docs on Success
copy /b "%file%" "\\10.0.238.209\Duplex\18inch_2UP_Pinless"
```

Comment: Please show the output from `echo %file%`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter substitution to insert `-ready` between the file's basename and extension.  See the last couple of pages of `help call` and `help for` for details.

Here's a solution that uses `call` to break a fully-qualified path down into its components, so you can insert what you need.  Does this work for you?

```
copy /b "%file%" "W:\IP5000_2-up\Input Folder"
TIMEOUT /T 60 /NOBREAK
call :appendready "w:\IP5000_ING_2-up\Processed Docs on Success\%file%" processed
copy /b "%processed%" "\\10.0.238.209\Duplex\18inch_2UP_Pinless"

goto :EOF

:appendready <filename> <var_to_populate>
set "%~2=%~dpn1-ready%~x1"
```

In pseudocode, the `:appendready` subroutine works like this:

```
set $2 = $1(drive:\path\name) + "-ready" + $1(extension)
```

Comment: the ready extension in the file name is been added by another process. I need the second copy command to see the original file name (mytest01) with the added ready word to the output file name (mytest01-ready).

Comment: @Patron0119 - So `mytest01` has no extension?  In that case, all you need to do is change `copy /b "%file%" "\\10.0.238.209\Duplex\18inch_2UP_Pinless"` to `copy /b "%file%-ready" "\\10.0.238.209\Duplex\18inch_2UP_Pinless"` in your original script.